# Compatibility of vsnprintf and the macros from inttypes

Tags: c, printf

I'm rewriting some code to be compatible with 32-bit and 64-bit architectures, and I'm having trouble with a vsnprintf call.  It doesn't appear that vsnprintf handles the fixed size integer types from inttypes.h properly on either architecture.

Here is the relevant code:

```
void formatString(char *buffer, int size, char *format, ...)
{
    va_list va;

    /* Format the data */
    va_start( va, format );
    vsnprintf( (char *)buffer, size, format, va );
    va_end( va );
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char buffer[2048];

    printf("The format string: %s\n", stringsLookup(0));
    formatString(&buffer[0], sizeof(buffer), stringsLookup(0), 1, 2);
    printf("The output string: %s\n", buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
The format string: action=DoSomething&Val1=%"PRIx32"&Val2=%x
The output string: action=DoSomething&Val1=%"PRIx32"&Val2=1
```

You can see that the %"PRIx32" portion of the format string was not replaced with the value '1' as expected.  Is this a known issue?  Is there a work around?

I will mention that if I hard code the strings in the source, the preprocessor appears to convert "%PRIu32" to the appropriate macro for the architecture and the call to vsnprintf works.  Unfortunately I need to be able to load the strings.

**Update**

Some additional background:  When I moved from a 32-bit system to a 64-bit system, I had to fix the size of certain variables.  I declared them as uint32_t.  I also changed the places where they were printed to clean up compiler warnings.  The previous code used `printf("%lx")`.  I used `printf("%"PRIx32)`.  I need to do something similar with the call to vsnprintf.

As I've mentioned, if I hard code the string in the source code, the preprocessor appears to convert "%"PRIx32 to "%lx" or "%x" appropriately.  Unfortunately, I'm running into trouble when I have to load the strings from a file.  The preprocessor can't help me there.

Comment: WHat is `stringsLookup(0)`?

Comment: It's a "char *stringsLookup(int index)" function that takes care of loading the strings from outside resources.  The string it would load would be "action=DoSomething&Val1=%"PRIx32"&Val2=%x".  That's what I used in printf statements elsewhere in the code, so that's what I used here.

Comment: I was asking because that's likely where the bug is, but I went and assumed that it was there in my answer.

Comment: I figured that function would get questions, which is why I printed out it's return value (the format string).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`PRIx32` is a macro whose name should not appear textually even in the format string. You are almost certainly using it wrong, unless it expands to a string that contains `"PRIx32"` (it almost certainly doesn't).

A typical use is `printf("Number: %" PRIx32 "...", arg);`.

In the typical idiom above, `"Number: %" PRIx32 "..."` is expanded to, say, `"Number: %" "lX" "..."`, which by a peculiarity of C syntax is equivalent to `"Number: %lX..."`

**If you need to create the format string dynamically, use `strcat` or other string-manipulation functions.** Do not write the equivalent of `"Number: %\"PRIx32\"..."`.

Just remember that `PRIx32` expands to a string literal, and don't write `"%PRIx32"`, that does not make sense.

**EDIT:**

If you are loading the format string from a file, information that I suggested you provide in a comment 45 minutes ago, then you have to do your own substitution when the file is loaded from. Invent a syntax similar to the % syntax of printf, and write your own function to recognize it and substitute it with what is right on the architecture the program is running on.

Note that from a security point of view, if you load format strings from a file, whoever controls the file [controls what the program does](http://www.cvedetails.com/cwe-details/134/Uncontrolled-Format-String.html).

Also note that `printf("Number: %llx\n", (unsigned long long) e);` almost always work. It can only disappoint you if your compiler has an integer type wider than `unsigned long long` and you use it.

Comment: @KeithThompson It did, I'll do it again. Thanks for your improvement.

Comment: I'm not trying to create the string dynamically.  I just want to use "PRIx32" instead of using %lx in the format string so the output string is the same regardless of architecture (32-bit vs 64-bit) when printing a uint32_t value.  I expected vsnprintf to understand PRIx32 in the format string.

Comment: @GrandAdmiral `vsnprintf` does not understand `"%PRIx32"`. It understands `"%lX"`. What makes you think that your program would be unportable if you wrote    `char * stringsLookup(int) { return "The format string: action=DoSomething&Val1=%" PRIx32 "&Va…"; }`    ?

Comment: @GrandAdmiral: At the risk of beating a dead horse, none if the `*printf` functions understand the string `"PRIx32"` (other than as an ordinary string with no special meaning). `PRIx32` is a macro that expands to a string that all the `*printf*` functions *do* understand. All the standard `*printf` functions recognize the same format strings.

Comment: If none of the *printf functions understand PRIx32 (or any of the other inttypes.h macros), then how can I expand the macro on the format string?  I've already changed the printf strings in my code to use PRIlx32 macros and didn't have a problem there.  It's only vsnprintf that I see problems.

Comment: If this helps, my goal is this:  Make sure int32_t variables are printed as 32-bit integers regardless of the architecture.  I don't want to use %l, since the definition of a "long" can vary.

Comment: @GrandAdmiral Either let C's syntax for string literal concatenation do its job, which is completely portable and will produce the correct result on both 32- and 64-bit architectures. Or do something dynamic (and if these string are not dynamic, a little silly) like `sprintf(destination_format, "Number: %%%s…", PRIx32);`

Comment: @PascalCuoq I'm sorry, but I don't understand why you keep bringing up string concatenation.  I'm just trying to use a different printf argument/macro to match the variable size.

Comment: @GrandAdmiral Well, you want to “make sure int32_t variables are printed as 32-bit integers regardless of the architecture”. This means incorporating into the format string **the contents** of `PRIx32`, which is a macro that expands to a string literal, into your format string. Incorporating the contents of a string into another string involves string concatenation. Hence my bringing it up. But I am getting tired of bringing it up, so please read any manual on how to use these macros properly. Perhaps it will make it clear in a way I failed to.

Comment: @GrandAdmiral `printf("%" PRIx32 "\n", UINT32_C(2147483648));` -- notice the PRIx32 is outside quotes. If your stringsLookup function returns a string containing an actual substring `\"PRIx32\"`, you should revise it to return a string of the form `"%" PRIx32`. `PRIx32` is a macro that gets replaced by the C preprocessor. Write it as `"%" PRIx32`, which will end up as `"%" "lx"` on some platforms. The C compiler will then concatenate the two strings, resulting in one format of `%lx`. Of course, if `"%" PRIx32` is `"%" "x"`, then it will become `%x`. PRIx32 should be outside any strings.

Comment: @ChronoKitsune Thanks, that was the key I needed to understand the problem - the format string was actually missing the " at the start and end of the string.  Apologies to Pascal Cuoq for just not understanding what he or she was telling me.  Sorry about that.

Comment: Oops, I guess it wasn't working.  Guess I'll have to keep looking for an answer.

Comment: @GrandAdmiral See the updated answer Pascal kindly provided. As noted, the fact that you are reading the strings from a file means you effectively are forced to parse the string yourself. You could hack around that if you know the command for the preprocessor, but as not all compilers allow for output of preprocessed source, the cross-platform solution is to handle it yourself.